# switching layouts causes crash with image backgrounds

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [switching xml layout causes crash in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870254/switching-xml-layout-causes-crash-in-android)

I have many xml layouts with image backgrounds and `Buttons`. I need to switch layouts so I use this function many times
`setContentView(R.layout...)`;

it causes crash at 4. or 5. call of `setContentView()` because of previous layouts... using of `System.gc();` `Runtime.getRuntime().gc();`

didn't work.

Comment: error log from logcat?  Also some code samples would probably help people answer your question

Comment: Why are you switching Layouts?

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of setting content view for activity every time, you can add and remove views(other xml layouts) to and from main layout based on requirement. For example

```
main_layout.addView(view);
```

before adding other view, you have to remove view like below

```
main_layout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
```

Hope it helps.